# adding a constraint that checks existence of stored proc

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

I am using SQL Server 2005 and in one of the tables i have a column that stores stored proc name. While inserting values in that column I want to ensure that a stored proc of that name exists in the database.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_MyColumn] CHECK ((SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(MyColumn) AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure')=1) = 1)
```

but this gives the following error

> Subqueries are not allowed in this
>   context. Only scalar expressions are
>   allowed.

How can I do this.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: As a side-note: I would use `sys.procedures` instead of `sys.sysobjects` - first of all, it's clearer what you do, and second, you don't have to define a object type to check for - it's already clear that it's a procedure you're looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are allowed:

```
create function dbo.IsProcedure(@ProcName sysname) returns bit as
return (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.sysobjects 
  where id = object_id(MyColumn) and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure')=1);
go

ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_MyTable_MyColumn]
CHECK (dbo.IsProcedure(MyColumn) = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that this type of constraint is only guaranteed to be true at the time a record is inserted or updated.  The proc can be dropped without consequence.  You may need to add a DDL trigger to catch things which get dropped which have references in the table and/or an exception reporting procedure which runs on a regular basis to monitor your system's health to ensure any procedure in the table actually exists.